# Skype runtime issue on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: skype, 18.04

I had done a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04. I installed Skype from the Ubuntu Software Store. However when I wanted to start up Skype it crashed so bad that the Ubuntu user was also logged out (!) This happened on Wayland and on X.org.

Comment: Odd that Skype was Preinstalled. I upgraded to 18.04 yesterday and it was not.

Comment: Now that you mention that ... I may have installed it originally myself from the Ubuntu Software Store. And that is the one that crashes.

Comment: @obelix93 Please always [edit] your question and add/change important details. Comments section is not a good or safe place for important info as comments get deleted easily.

Answer (score 2):

I eventually resolved it by uninstalling Skype and then not going to the Ubuntu Store but to the [Skype website](https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/) and download and install Skype from there. Now I have it working without any problems!

Answer (score 0):

Logging on to X.org session instead of Wayland has fixed the issue for me.